# Python Showing a gif as background using Tkinter and PIL

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to display an animated gif as background for my GUI but i can't do it, console shows this error:
Also i already tried every solution i found on this website and google, i read PIL and Tkinter documentation too but apparently nothing works for me

```
File "C:\Users\user\.spyder-py3\temporal.py", line 32, in <listcomp>
    frames = [Image(file='079.gif',format = 'gif -index %i' %(i)) for i in range(79)]

    TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

This is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import os
from PIL import Image

root= tk.Tk()
root.title("SCP-079")

root.resizable(0,0)
root.iconbitmap("079.ico")
root.geometry("540x360")


frames = [Image(file='079.gif',format = 'gif -index %i' %(i)) for i in range(79)]

def update(ind):
    frame = frames[ind]
    ind += 1
    if ind>78: #With this condition it will play gif infinitely
    ind = 0
    gif.configure(image=frame)
    root.after(100, update, ind)

gif = root.Label
gif.pack()
root.after(0, update, 0)
root.mainloop()
```

This is the gif i want to use

[079.gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeEOy.gif)

i tried to do it in a different way but now i don't know how to display it

```
import tkinter as tk
import PIL.Image

root= tk.Tk()
root.title("SCP-079")

root.resizable(0,0)
root.iconbitmap("079.ico")
root.geometry("540x360")


gif=[PIL.Image.open(fp='079.gif', mode='r', formats=None)]


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You seem to be assuming that `Image` is something that it is not. In this code `Image` is a module, not a function or class.

Comment: Then what's the correct way to show the gif?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got your code working.
Note that you haven't set everything on it. You must to "Image.open" in your file before.
"Image" is imported as PIM from PIL to prevent conflict.

```
import os, tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image as PIM, ImageTk
from tkinter import*

root= tk.Tk()
root.title("SCP-079")
root.resizable(0,0)
root.iconbitmap("079.ico")
root.geometry("540x360")

im = PIM.open("C:\\...\\CeEOy.gif")
ph = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
gif = Label(root, image = ph, bg="black", bd=3)
gif.image = ph
framnr = 79
frames = [PhotoImage(file="C:\\...\\CeEOy.gif",
                format = 'gif -index %i' %(i)) for i in range(framnr)]

def update(ind):
    frame = frames[ind]
    ind += 1
    if ind>78: 
         ind = 0
    gif.configure(image = frame)
    root.after(100, update, ind)
    
gif = Label(root)
gif.pack()
root.after(0, update, 0)
root.mainloop()
```